# Mono HTTPS Error - "Error Writing Headers"

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssl, mono

**Scope:**

I am trying to integrate with an external centralized [Logging service](http://www.logz.io) provider, using `HTTPS` requests to post the logs to it.

We are running `C#` on top of `Mono`, using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as the OS.

We have been using mono for years already, so we are somehow familiar with it's behaviors and potential flaws / issues.

**Previous Setup**

When you google this issue, you find basically two solutions to it, and none of them worked to me, for this case. Here's what I have done so far

[Basic Mono-Complete Setup](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) + ca-certificates-mono (that would potentially solve HTTPS related issues).

Other than that, I know that mono does not trust any certificate by default, having it's own certificates-chain, and that we have to import them to it. To do that I ran `mozroots --import --sync --ask-remove` and it printed me that "140 certificates were downloaded and installed".

Aditionally, we overrode the CertificateValidationCallback using this nasty one-liner:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

None of the above solved our issue.

**Errors, Errors and more Errors:**

`Note that all of the codes below do work on Windows.`

So far we have tried:

- Using Native .NET WebClient Async Calls (`PostAsync`).

As the result, we get errors such as `Cant find file system.net.http.dll`, and once we actually copy the one from our windows system to it, we get another error `Task Exception` (can't remember the exact message there).

- Using [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient)

Apparently, using this client on Xamarin programs tend to solve the issues people have, but we still get the same errors listed above, using the standard `HttpClient` class from `.NET`

- Writing our own WebRequests Wrapper

This was the closest we got to an actual solution, that leads to `Error Writing Headers` when running it on Mono.

**Small Code Sample:**

```
using (WebRequests webClient = new WebRequests ())
{
                // Client Configuration
                webClient.BufferSize       = 32 * 1024;
                webClient.Accept           = "application/json";
                webClient.ContentType      = "application/json; charset=" + Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName;
                webClient.Timeout          = 60000;
                webClient.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
                webClient.Encoding         = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;

                // Dummy Logz Payload - One Json Per Line
                string LogzPayload = "{id:'1', value='1'}\n{id:'2', value='2'}";

                // Request to Logz
                webClient.Post ("https://listener-4.logz.io:8071/?token=OUR_TOKEN&type=json", LogzPayload);
}
```

**Update 1:**

Just tried running the following command and got an exception right away:

```
certmgr --ssl https://listener-4.logz.io:8071/?token=OUR_TOKEN&type=json --machine
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. --->     System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. --->  Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord  (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x4192e470 + 0x00132> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord  (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x4192e3a0 + 0x00031> in <filename  unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x4192abb0 + 0x00225> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: what version of Mono are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Mono but I know that they use their own TLS stack whereas .NET uses the TLS stack from the OS. If I'm correct than the available cipher suites are defined in [CipherSuiteFactory.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/CipherSuiteFactory.cs) which shows that no ECDHE and no DHE ciphers are available. But from what I can see the server supports only ECDHE and DHE ciphers and thus there will be no shared ciphers and the TLS handshake will fail. The ciphers supported by the server are:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

Most of these are ciphers  need TLS 1.2 which is not supported by Mono at all (see [State of TLS in Mono](http://tirania.org/blog//archive/2015/Aug.html)). But even the rest is DHE or ECDHE only which Mono does not seem to support. They are actively working on a [new TLS stack](https://github.com/mono/mono-tls) but it looks like it is not done yet.

If you have access to the server you might try to configure the cipher AES256-SHA which is probably the best cipher currently supported by Mono.

Comment: WoW. That's a hell of an answer ! :)

So what you're saying is that, unless either Mono releases it's new TLS Stack, or Logz adds support for other chiphers, there's no way we can make it work, right ?

Aditionally, how did you checked the server's supported ciphers ?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins: Yes, that's what I'm saying. I've checked the ciphers with [my own Perl tool](https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl) but you could probably also use [the Python tool sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) instead.

Comment: Have you tested logz.io or the API one ?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins: I've tested the API, i.e. listener-4.logz.io:8071. The homepage logz.io itself has different ciphers including some which should work with Mono (like AES256-SHA). But the name for `https://logz.io` does not match (cloudfront.net instead) so I guess it is not intended to be used with https (homepage only, browser complains too).

Comment: I just had a call with the support team from Logz and they confirmed me what you are saying. Those are the cyphers implemented by them. As for mono, you are also correct, they do not support those cyphers, so what I will have to do is to fallback to HTTP requests instead of HTTPS ones.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to switch to Ubuntu 16.04 because that brings a version of Mono's packages that syncs certificates by default and therefore you don't need to run mozroots, and you will more likely to not have problems around this area.

Comment: Ubuntu is not the problem. As @SteffenUllrich pointed out, Mono has it's own TLS stack, that is faulty and misses implementations of some cyphers, resulting in non-functional HTTPS Handshakes.